# C++/CLI в смешанном режиме (/clr)

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие либо ограничения при программировании на C++/CLI в смешанном режиме (/clr)?

Например можно ли пользоваться ассемблерными вставками?  Можно ли смешивать между собой структуры и алгоритмы из STL и .Net?

Comment: Алгоритмы STL работают лишь с нативными объектами, методы .NET работают лишь с объектами .NET. Что вам даёт C++/CLI, так это возможность (1) легко конвертировать туда и обратно арифметические типы (и немного сложнее — строки) (2) в пределах одной функции смешивать нативный код и вызовы .NET-функций.

А зачем вам это? C++/CLI — ужасно неудобная штука, старайтесь сделать на ней как можно меньше.

Comment: Спасибо что предупредили, просто было интересно что за чудо такое.